# Socket.io server over https

Tags: https, websocket, socket.io

I tried to convert the socket IO getting started example to https like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const app = require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("privkey.pem"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("fullchain.pem"),
}, handler)
const io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(443);

function handler (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
}

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

But running the following in my browser does not work:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com");
```

But I received the following error:

```
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at wss://example.com/.
```

I tried to debug this by running this curl command:

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: example.com" -H "Origin: https://example.com " https://example.com
```

and the result was:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

None of the console logging code is reached and there are no errors on the node script while doing all of this.

Why can't I connect to my websocket server?

Comment: I haven't figure this out entirely yet, but I think it may be related to this issue: https://github.com/websockets/ws/issues/1458

Answer (score 0):

According to [doc](https://socket.io/docs/#What-Socket-IO-is-not):

> Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket as a transport when possible, it adds some metadata to each packet: the packet type, the namespace and the packet id when a message acknowledgement is needed. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a WebSocket server either.

So this is not correct:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com");
```

You should use:

```
const socket = io('https://your-server-address');
```